# How to generate a link from controller to razorpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I need to create a link of type string from my mvc controller to a razor page.
Asp.Net Core 2.2.
I use IUrlHelper:

```
int number = 4;
string callbackUrl = Url.Page(
   "/Test/Name",
   pageHandler: null,
   values: new { number },
   protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

the callbackUrl is null. This works from the razor pages code behind, but not from a controller. From the controller the UrlHelper inherits from ControllerBase and from razor PageModel, so there are two different implementations. But how could I get the controller urlhelper to work so that I can create a razorpages link?

(Another, slightly different issue, is how to generate links like this from class libraries outside controllers in a good way?).

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.2 project?

Comment: yes, this is on 2.2

Comment: You can generally use the new [`LinkGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to generate URLs to any page or action within your application. Even within libraries (those should take the generator as a dependency then).

Comment: linkgenerator looks promising, @poke ! I'll look into it! It might just solve all my problems in life

Comment: @poke Problem is LinkGenerator not working for Razor Page from controller method. Actually OP is trying to generate link for Razor Pages from controller method.

Comment: @TanvirArjel LinkGenerator is designed to work from anywhere within the web application. The UrlHelper is dependent on where it is being executed.

Comment: @poke Yeh! But problem is its not working for Razor Page, only works for Controller action method. I have spend one hour but no luck.

Comment: asp.net-mvc and razor-pages are two distinctly different technologies.  Why are you using both?  If you are only using MVC you should change your [tag:razor-pages] with just [tag:razor] as the question is obviously ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Having a mixed environment using both MVC and Pages is a fully supported and not that unlikely scenario. There is really nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I have this code inside of an MVC controller, which is the exact same code to generate the URL that’s shown in the question:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    int number = 4;
    string callbackUrl = Url.Page(
        "/Test/Name",
        pageHandler: null,
        values: new { number },
        protocol: Request.Scheme);

    return Json(new
    {
        callbackUrl
    });
}
```

In addition, I have a Razor page at `/Pages/Test/Name.cshtml` with the following contents:

```
@page "{number}"
Hello @RouteData.Values["number"]!
```

Note the specification of the route parameter `number`, which matches the route parameter given in the `Url.Page` call within the controller.

If I run that application and open up `http://localhost:5000/Home/Test`, then I get the following response which is exactly what I expect to get generated:

```
{"callbackUrl":"http://localhost:5000/Test/Name/4"}
```

If you are seeing `null` instead, chances are that the route value `number` does not match the parameter within your Razor page. In that case, the routing does not find a matching Razor page.

If you have an unparameterized Razor page (i.e. just `@page` without an argument), the the response from the MVC action should be the following where the route value is provided as a query argument:

```
{"callbackUrl":"http://localhost:5000/Test/Name?number=4"}
```

---

Instead of the UrlHelper, which depends on ambient values and as such is best used within controller actions or Razor views, you can also use the new [`LinkGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The LinkGenerator will generally give you the same experience as the UrlHelper but does not require an ambient setup, so it can be used in the same way regardless of where you actually are.

Comment: You could be right! I could have written the wrong parameter. A difficult bug to see if that is the case (and embarrassing for the time waste). I will look into it tomorrow and

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core 2.2 introduced the new `LinkGenerator` service, a singleton that can be called outside the context of a HTTP call in order to generate a URL string.

Example:

```
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
  protected readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
  / ...
```

(and then, in the action method):

```
return _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
     httpContext,
     controller: "Home",
     action: "Index",
     values: new { id=1 });
```

Comment: Problem is `LinkGenerator `not working for Razor Page from controller method. Actually OP is trying to generate link for Razor Pages from controller method.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I am using it inside controller methods without issues (which is what the OP is asking for: "*from my mvc controller* to a razor page"): why are you saying it's not working?

Comment: Yes! For controller action method its working fine but not working for Razor page route.

Comment: Then the question is solved, since the OP is clearly looking for a method to be used **within a MVC Controller**. By the way, for razor pages you can keep using the existing *@Url.Action* API, which now internally uses the new method (since ASP.NET Core 2.2 preview 3).

Comment: You got things wrong! Will be generated inside MVC controller method but route is 
actually Razor Page route. Its not working!

Comment: Op clearly says that `the callbackUrl is null. This works from the razor pages code behind, but not from a controller.` . I have also tried in my side for an hour and really not working.

Comment: OP is using Url.Page from a controller method, which will obviously return null. My code *replaces the one mentioned by the OP and will return a non-null, actual URL that can be used everywhere*, which seems to me exactly what the OP is looking for. I honestly don't understand what you're trying to do, but I suggest to ask your own (different) question because this one definitely has an answer now. Side note: if you're trying to generate a direct link to a Razor page without a controller action method serving it, you are playing outside the "VC part" of the MVC scope (Controller -> View).

Comment: I am trying to this to be working inside controller method: `string pathByPage = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(httpContext: HttpContext, page: "/Identity/Account/Login", values: new { returnUrl = ""  } );` but its not working. Its returning null. Have you got it?

Comment: Both `LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage` and `LinkGenerator.GetPathByAction` internally calls `CreateAddress` + `Get*ByAddress`, which will check that both the relevant controllers and action methods exists: are you sure that they actually do exist? Have you tried to use `LinkGenerator.GetPathByPage` with the actual action and controller and check if it works?